Calendar view for football league - Lazy VGrid
I'm quite new to SwiftUI and I'm trying to build my first app.
I have a data model file like the one below:
import Foundation

struct CalendarioPartite: Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    let stagione: String
    let giornata: Int
    let datapartita: String
    let squadracasa: String
    let golsquadracasa: Int
    let squadratrasferta: String
    let golsquadratrasferta: Int
    
    init(stagione: String, giornata: Int, datapartita: String, squadracasa: String, golsquadracasa: Int, squadratrasferta: String, golsquadratrasferta: Int) {
        self.stagione = stagione
        self.giornata = giornata
        self.datapartita = datapartita
        self.squadracasa = squadracasa
        self.golsquadracasa = golsquadracasa
        self.squadratrasferta = squadratrasferta
        self.golsquadratrasferta = golsquadratrasferta
    }
    
    static func testCalendario() -> [CalendarioPartite] {
        [CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 1, datapartita: "04/09/2023", squadracasa: "Castelnovese Castelnuovo", golsquadracasa: 1, squadratrasferta: "Junior Asca", golsquadratrasferta: 3),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 1, datapartita: "04/09/2023", squadracasa: "Casalnoceto", golsquadracasa: 3, squadratrasferta: "Cassine", golsquadratrasferta: 1),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 1, datapartita: "04/09/2023", squadracasa: "Nizza Valle Belbo", golsquadracasa: 0, squadratrasferta: "Libarna", golsquadratrasferta: 2),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 1, datapartita: "04/09/2023", squadracasa: "Quargnento", golsquadracasa: 1, squadratrasferta: "Audace Club Boschese", golsquadratrasferta: 1),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 1, datapartita: "04/09/2023", squadracasa: "Solero", golsquadracasa: 1, squadratrasferta: "Viguzzolese", golsquadratrasferta: 1),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 1, datapartita: "04/09/2023", squadracasa: "Vignolese", golsquadracasa: 1, squadratrasferta: "Pozzolese", golsquadratrasferta: 1),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 1, datapartita: "04/09/2023", squadracasa: "Spinettese", golsquadracasa: 4, squadratrasferta: "Calliano", golsquadratrasferta: 1),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 2, datapartita: "11/09/2023", squadracasa: "Audace Club Boschese", golsquadracasa: 3, squadratrasferta: "Castelnovese Castelnuovo", golsquadratrasferta: 0),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 2, datapartita: "11/09/2023", squadracasa: "Calliano", golsquadracasa: 3, squadratrasferta: "Vignolese", golsquadratrasferta: 3),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 2, datapartita: "11/09/2023", squadracasa: "Cassine", golsquadracasa: 1, squadratrasferta: "Nizza Valle Belbo", golsquadratrasferta: 2),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 2, datapartita: "11/09/2023", squadracasa: "Junior Asca", golsquadracasa: 2, squadratrasferta: "Spinettese", golsquadratrasferta: 2),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 2, datapartita: "11/09/2023", squadracasa: "Libarna", golsquadracasa: 1, squadratrasferta: "Quargnento", golsquadratrasferta: 1),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 2, datapartita: "11/09/2023", squadracasa: "Pozzolese", golsquadracasa: 0, squadratrasferta: "Spinettese", golsquadratrasferta: 0),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 2, datapartita: "11/09/2023", squadracasa: "Viguzzolese", golsquadracasa: 2, squadratrasferta: "Casalnoceto", golsquadratrasferta: 2),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 3, datapartita: "18/09/2023", squadracasa: "Casalnoceto", golsquadracasa: 3, squadratrasferta: "Pozzolese", golsquadratrasferta: 1),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 3, datapartita: "18/09/2023", squadracasa: "Castelnovese Castelnuovo", golsquadracasa: 4, squadratrasferta: "Quargnento", golsquadratrasferta: 3),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 3, datapartita: "18/09/2023", squadracasa: "Libarna", golsquadracasa: 4, squadratrasferta: "Cassine", golsquadratrasferta: 2),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 3, datapartita: "18/09/2023", squadracasa: "Nizza Valle Belbo", golsquadracasa: 3, squadratrasferta: "Viguzzolese", golsquadratrasferta: 1),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 3, datapartita: "18/09/2023", squadracasa: "Solero", golsquadracasa: 5, squadratrasferta: "Calliano", golsquadratrasferta: 0),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 3, datapartita: "18/09/2023", squadracasa: "Spinettese", golsquadracasa: 3, squadratrasferta: "Audace Club Boschese", golsquadratrasferta: 1),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 3, datapartita: "18/09/2023", squadracasa: "Vignolese", golsquadracasa: 0, squadratrasferta: "Junior Asca", golsquadratrasferta: 2),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 4, datapartita: "25/09/2023", squadracasa: "Audace Club Boschese", golsquadracasa: 2, squadratrasferta: "Vignolese", golsquadratrasferta: 0),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 4, datapartita: "25/09/2023", squadracasa: "Calliano", golsquadracasa: 0, squadratrasferta: "Casalnoceto", golsquadratrasferta: 0),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 4, datapartita: "25/09/2023", squadracasa: "Castelnovese Castelnuovo", golsquadracasa: 2, squadratrasferta: "Libarna", golsquadratrasferta: 2),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 4, datapartita: "25/09/2023", squadracasa: "Junior Asca", golsquadracasa: 0, squadratrasferta: "Solero", golsquadratrasferta: 3),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 4, datapartita: "25/09/2023", squadracasa: "Pozzolese", golsquadracasa: 2, squadratrasferta: "Nizza Valle Belbo", golsquadratrasferta: 2),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 4, datapartita: "25/09/2023", squadracasa: "Quargnento", golsquadracasa: 1, squadratrasferta: "Spinettese", golsquadratrasferta: 2),
         CalendarioPartite(stagione: "2023/2024", giornata: 4, datapartita: "25/09/2023", squadracasa: "Viguzzolese", golsquadracasa: 4, squadratrasferta: "Cassine", golsquadratrasferta: 0),]
    }
    
}


This is representing the data structure of 4 different days in a football league with teams and results.
Now I'd like to build a view where the four different days are displayed according to a grid layout.
Therefore I started to build the grid item for a single day. And this works as expected.
The tricky part is then to use this as a function to be displayed into a LazyVGrid layout so that all the four days are displayed.
I'm struggling with this in the view file:
import SwiftUI

struct CalendarioView: View {

    @State var Calendario: [CalendarioPartite] = CalendarioPartite.testCalendario()
    @State var stagione: String = "2023/2024"
    
    private var giornate = Array(1...4)
    private let adaptiveColumn = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 150))]
    var partiteCampionato: [CalendarioPartite] {
        CalendarioPartite.testCalendario().filter{
            $0.stagione == stagione
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: adaptiveColumn, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(giornate, id: \.self) {
                    giornata in
                    giornataDisplay()
                }
            }
            
        }.padding()
    }
    
    func giornataDisplay() {
        
       VStack {
            
            var partiteGiornata: [CalendarioPartite] {
                partiteCampionato.filter {
                    $0.giornata = giornate
                }
            }
            
            Text("Giornata \(giornate)")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .padding()
            
            Grid {
                ForEach (partiteGiornata) { partita in
                    GridRow {
                        Text(partita.squadracasa)
                            .gridCellAnchor(UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5))
                        Text("-")
                        Text(partita.squadratrasferta)
                            .gridCellAnchor(UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5))
                        Text("=")
                        Text(partita.golsquadracasa, format: .number)
                        Text("-")
                        Text(partita.golsquadratrasferta, format: .number)
                    }
                    
                }

            }
            
        }
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .circular))
        
    }
    
}


In fact, I'm getting two different errors:

"No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression'" in correspondence to the call of the function within the ForEach
"Cannot assign to property: 'giornata' is a 'let' constant" within the function where I'm filtering the data to the "giornata" value. I guess this is depending by the fact that "giornate" var is an array. Am I right?

Can you please assist me in achieving my desired result?
Thanks,
A.


= is not the same as ==


If I put "==" it says: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and '[Int]'

And? The message is pretty clear and I have no idea what you want to do with that filter so I can’t really advise you

As I'd like to loop through the different "Giornate" and that filter should select and show only the lines of the array which are related to that giornata

But why do you want to filter on an array? Maybe you should use a ForEach instead since it's an array?
